# Azure web service doesnt display the content

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The Azure app service is not displaying the Node.js angular app deployed from VS Code.

Getting the issue You dont have permission to  view this directory or page.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some context? Maybe a way to reproduce or the tutorial you are doing?

Comment: Actually using Deploy to webapp in VS code, the Angular Node.js app is deployed to Azure web app. The files are available in the wwwroot folder.                       There is error page displayed when checked in scm debugger console  with                                                               HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden 
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: Is it similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1479031/how-to-fix-azure-permission-load-page-error ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred this links for [AngularProject](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt0) , creating a web Apps in [Azure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/microsoft-azure-create-web-apps-in-azure/)  and publish the application to   [web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-publish-webapp-app-service-vs-code/4-publish-app-azure-app-service-vs-code)  with visual studio code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Install inside the project `npm install -g @angular/cli`

**Verify App Service Configuration:**

- Make sure the web application is set up properly with the requisite runtime stack (Node.js) and other parameters.
- Verify that the deployment from Visual Studio Code (VS Code) went off without a hitch.

**Check File Structure:**

- The files for your Angular Node.js app should be in the correct directory (wwwroot) in the web app's file structure.
- Make that all of the relevant files, including index.html, main.js, and other Angular-specific files, are present in the right place.

**Verify Permissions:**

- Verify the web application's access privileges and file permissions.
- To ensure that both the web server and the user using the app have access to the files, make sure the appropriate permissions are configured.

**Enable Directory Browsing:**

- When no specific page is requested, you can enable directory browsing in your web app's configuration to display a list of the directory's contents.
- Go to the Configuration settings for your web app in the Azure portal and turn on the "Directory browsing" option.

**Check Routing and Configuration:**

- Ensure that the web server is properly configured to handle these routes if you are using client-side routing in your Angular app.
- For instance, if you are utilizing Angular's "PathLocationStrategy," you may need to set up the web server such that it directs all requests to your primary index.html file.

**Review Web Server Logs:**

- Look through the web app's logs to see if there are any error or warning messages that can reveal more details about the problem.
- Visit the Diagnose and fix problems section of your web app in the Azure portal to access the logs.

[image]

[image]